# I want to run/download the snake game on my computer, but it wont download

Tags: games

[The code i imputed and the error message i got out of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUHZy.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. First run the commands `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`.
2. Then to install snake run the command:

   - `sudo apt-get install nsnake`

[image]

3. To start the game run the command:

   - `nsnake`

[image]

Comment: hi there, please let me know if my answer helped you out, or there are more issues with trying to install that game.